# how to simulate keyboard input for a program in C

Tags: c, ipc, iostream, stdio

I have a binary of a program that waits for an input using scanf. I need to write a C code that will be able to simulate keyboard input. i.e. close the stdin pointer for that binary and instead repoint it to a file.
I used this code

```
int main()
{
        FILE *fin;
        int result;
        char string[80];
        close(0);

        fin = fopen("text", "r");

        if(NULL == fin)
        {
                printf("Unable to open file.");
                return 0;
        }
        dup(fin);
        return 0;
}
```

But i found that each program has its own stdin pointer. Is there a way for me to simulate 
keyboard input for one binary from another C program ?

Comment: I only have the binary for the first program so i cant change its code, I just need the scanf to read froma  file instead of keyboard buffer. :/ help ?

Comment: It's less than one minute between asking your question and your comment. :/ patience ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's not a program you're looking for, it's capabilities of your shell:

```
 program < input.txt
```

This way you push input.txt as stdin to program.

If you want a program, then you can just run a program and reroute it's output to the other programs input.

Comment: so youre saying to write a shell script ? Could you elaborate on what youve answered ? I dont understand... sorry :/

Comment: what is the "program" in your answer ? Is it the program id ? or is that the way to execute it ? Will it always take input from the file instead of keyboard as my binary takes input multiple times ?

Comment: you, sir, are a genius... I am an idiot ! I've done this about a million times to redirect the output to a file, never crossed my mind that i could do the same with input... Thank you !

Answer (score 2):

You can use a simple `pipe` when calling the programs as a basic measure.

Another way would be to make your keyboard simulator act as a launcher. It should start the program you are testing with `stdin` as your simulator's `stdout`.

You can do the latter by `fork`ing your program and use the parent process to create a  pipe and the child process to reopen `stdin` (even `stdout`) using a file descriptor to that pipe and `exec` the program you want to supply the input to.

See [this](http://linux.die.net/man/2/pipe) for **pipes** and [this](http://www.thinkage.ca/english/gcos/expl/c/lib/fdopen.html) for **file descriptors** (as creating a `pipe` will give you only a file descriptor).

P.S.: Sorry about not being able to provide code at the moment, but I'm not anywhere near a UNIX workstation and a bit too rusty on UNIX OS programming to write reliable code from memory.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% sure, but if you use one of exec functions to launch your binary program from your C code it should work. Since because yes its hard to explain). For more info try man page:

```
man 3 exec
```

Most of the time exec* is used together with fork, but in your case I don't think you need to fork.

Answer (score 0):

You can close the standard input file descriptor, and open the file you want to read from instead, if you don't want to use this facility in the shell for some reason. It will get the number of the just closed fd, this is most likely how your shell implement redirection as well.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

int main(void)
{
    int fd;
    char buf[128];

    close(STDIN_FILENO);

    fd = open("./testfile", O_RDONLY);
    if(fd < 0) return 1;

    scanf("%127[ a-z0-9]", buf);
    puts(buf);

    close(fd);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The Shell is the program that provides the command prompt to terminal sessions.  It supports a simple programming language, as described in its [Wiki article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shell_script).

In general, when you see an unfamiliar term, Wikipedia and search engines become powerful allies.  Use them, and life will quickly become better -- and your knowledge will grow exponentially.

Hope that this helps.